# How can i calculate date in php

Tags: php

Actually this is a bit tricky. I'm setting a food delivery system. When a buyer buys food from this webpage, he gets a mail that will says when the food will be delivered (an estimated time of delivery). If he buys between 00:00AM to 10:00AM, he gets his meal at 1230 PM. If he buy buys between 14:00 to 23:59, he gets his meal the next day at 1230PM. Needless to say, the food service is closed of taking order between 10:01 to 13:59. I already have the mailer system written, the only thing i don't have is the code to calculate when his food will be delivered. Can anybody help? Thanks

Comment: What do you have so far, and how doesn't it work?

Comment: Hint: `if (time() < strtotime('12:30'))`...

Comment: I have the mailer script done, it can send all the mail i want. One of the thing i want to write on this mail is the estimated time of delivery, which i don't know how to start

Comment: Deceze: it has to say the exact date: "In 21-02-2012 at 12:30 PM will arrive your meal" something like this, this only says when he bought the food between 00:00AM to 10:00AM of 21-02, if he buys between 14:00 to 23:59 on the same day, it will say "In 22-02-2012 at 12:30 PM will arrive your meal"

Comment: That's why it's only a hint. You'll have to figure out `if` the current `time()` is after/before some cutoff point like `strtotime('12:30')`, if so, delivery time will be x `else` it will be `y`. What do you specifically have a problem with? Comparing times? Formatting time strings? `if`/`else` logic?

Comment: I'm having trouble with range of times: the 00:00AM to 10:00AM, how can i count that?? What i want is something like this: if time() is between 00:00 AM to 10AM, delivery time will be x, else will be x+1day

Comment: chenci, see my answer below.  Take the date, convert it to an int, and run that through getdate() to make an array with an "hours" value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this shell-executable.  It assumes that the order time (`$orders`) is "now".

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php
<?php

$orders=array(
  "2012-02-21 09:21:00",
  "2012-02-21 10:45:00",
  "2012-02-21 14:10:00"
);

function ordertime($when) {
  $datearray=getdate(strtotime($when));
  if ($datearray['hours'] < 10) {
    // order ships today
    return strtotime("today 12:30");
  } else
  if ($datearray['hours'] < 14) {
    // we can't take this order
    return(FALSE);
  } else {
    // order ships tomorrow
    return strtotime("tomorrow 12:30");
  }
}

date_default_timezone_set("America/Toronto");

foreach ($orders as $oneorder) {
  $delivery=ordertime($oneorder);
  if ($delivery) {
    printf("%s: %s - %s\n", $oneorder, $delivery, strftime("%Y-%m-%d %T", $delivery));
  } else {
    printf("%s: INVALID ORDER TIME\n", $oneorder);
  }
}
```

When I run it, output looks like this:

```
ghoti@pc$ ./test.php
2012-02-21 09:21:00: 1329845400 - 2012-02-21 12:30:00
2012-02-21 10:45:00: INVALID ORDER TIME
2012-02-21 14:10:00: 1329931800 - 2012-02-22 12:30:00
ghoti@pc$
```

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: YES exacly what i'm looking for. The date_default_timezone_set is for php5, what alternative i have for php4??

Comment: Not sure there's an "alternative" for PHP4...  I don't have a PHP4 box to play on anymore, so I suggest you test it.  I suspect that your times will either be interpreted as GMT or as local to the server.  Either way, you can adjust if necessary simply by adding or removing the number of seconds that separates you from GMT.

Comment: Hi, today i finally have the time to try the code in php in a windows (my test machine), it seems i can't output strftime, i don't know why this the output. `2012-02-21 09:21:00: 1330018200 - 2012-02-21 10:45:00: INVALID ORDER TIME 2012-02-21 14:10:00: 1330104600 -`

Comment: Never mind i found out, it seems that strftime is not acepting %T (don't know why) but is acepting %H:%M:%S

Comment: ghoti i have a question, how could i modify your ordertime function so it can take orders only monday to friday?? By the way thanks for the info above

Comment: Sure, you can check the [getdate()](http://php.net/getdate) documentation to see what's in the array it outputs.  You can easily add an `if ()` segment to the function I wrote to test for values or ranges of `$datearray['wday']`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this.

```
$time = date('H');
if($time <= 10){
  $delivery_time = time('d-m-Y').'12:30pm';
}else if($time >= 14){
  $delivery_time = date("d-m-Y",strtotime("+1 days")).'12:30pm';
}
```